# Charset conversion between Android & iOS in notification

Tags: android, ios

I have an application that send notification between Android -> Android, iOS -> iOS and Android to iOS.

when I used non-Latin chars, notification between Android to iOS is shown as strange chars.

I think there difference between default charset used on iOS and Android, and I might need to do conversion between them, did anybody have slimier issue, and found a solution?

Comment: show the example of these "strange chars". how do you send this infomation? via remote server using DB?

Comment: strange chars like "????", info send via server that runs Java tomcat, there is no DB in between, notice it works fine between Android to Android, but not between iOs and Android